# Using a non existing UID for a docker container - what is the meaning or implications?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I read a lot about running a docker container with different users (i.e different than root).
I was wondering, since its possible to run a docker container with a UID that does not exist on the host, what is the meaning of this? what should I expect?
for example, assume the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
COPY my-app /app/
WORKDIR /app
USER 110011:110011
CMD ["/app/my-app"]
```

Assuming my-app doesn't require any special permissions, this works.
So I was wondering, what does this mean in term of the host and its user.
I know its nameless, but is it really a non existing user? and what does this mean?

I assume that I should expect no permissions on the file system in the container.
anything else I should be wary about?

any thoughts would be welcome.

Thanks!